# In vim, why does :tselect show me the wrong list?

Tags: vim, ctags

I have this code open in vim:

```
$this->mockEvolve(...);
```

When I do a `Ctrl + ]` with my cursor over the `m`, it brings me to its definition.

However, when I run `:ts` when my cursor is over the `m`, vim shows me this list of tags:

```
  # pri kind tag               file
> 1 F   f    mockGet           <filename>
               public function mockGet(...)
```

I run into this problem a lot (not just with this function). Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:help :tselect` gives you the answer:

> When [ident] is not given, the last tag name from the
>   tag stack is used.

It uses the last jumped-to tag, not the word under the cursor. To insert that into the command-line, use `Ctrl-R Ctrl-W`.

Comment: Wow, I just spent 3 months using :ts as though it listed all the tags under my cursor. A case of RTFM. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you like that behavior, you can define your own command for it: `command! Tselect execute 'tselect' expand('<cword>')`

Comment: I might just do that!

Comment: Also, try `g]` and `g^]`; they work like `^]` (automatically using the keyword under/after the cursor), but use `:tselect` and `:tjump` (respectively) instead of `:tag`; `:tjump` is like `:tselect`, but skips the prompt if there is only one matching item.